# androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException error in play console

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Please help. There is an error like this in play cosole. I can not track it on my devices in the release version.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3311)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3460)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2047)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:224)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7590)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:539)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:950)
Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: 
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.instantiate (FragmentFactory.java:134)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.instantiate (FragmentState.java:77)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreSaveState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2456)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState (FragmentController.java:194)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:279)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:85)
  at com.project.smolentsev.idleclick.play.PlayActivity.onCreate (PlayActivity.java:82)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7893)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7880)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1307)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3286)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0 (Class.java:2332)
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor (Class.java:1728)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.instantiate (FragmentFactory.java:124)
```

My PlayActivity

```
public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    private String fileName = "data.txt";
  
    Dialog dialog;
    private static boolean flagThread;
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

        flagThread = true;

        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        checkFirstRun(); 

        loadJson();
        
        
        loadFragment(new PlayFragment(data));

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");

        PlayFragment fragobj = new PlayFragment(data);
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

        ImageButton office_button = findViewById(R.id.btn_office);
        office_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                data.setDate(0);
                saveJson();
                Intent office = new Intent(PlayActivity.this, office.class);
                startActivity(office);
                d("RelaxPlayyOfice", String.valueOf(data.getRelax()));

            }
        });

    }

   
 
    @Override
    public void  onBackPressed()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(PlayActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
    {
        Fragment fragment=null;

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.navigation_play:

            {   ImageButton office_button = findViewById(R.id.btn_office);
                office_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fragment = new PlayFragment(data);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.navigation_shop:
            {  ImageButton office_button = findViewById(R.id.btn_office);
                 office_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                fragment = new ShopFragment(data);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.navigation_back:
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }

    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment){
        if(fragment != null)
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_play, fragment).commit();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


   

    private void openCancelDialog(){
        dialog = new Dialog(PlayActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.cancel_dialog);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        }

        ImageButton cancel_del=dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        cancel_del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
                del_progress();
               dialog.dismiss();


            }
        });

        dialog.show();
}
    private void openTutorial1(){
        dialog = new Dialog(PlayActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_tutorial_1);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        }

        ImageButton cancel_del=dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        cancel_del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                openTutorial2();

            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
    private void openTutorial2(){
        dialog = new Dialog(PlayActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_tutorial_2);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        }

        ImageButton cancel_del=dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        cancel_del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                dialog.dismiss();


            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

My PlayFragment

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class PlayFragment extends Fragment {

    private Data data;

    private long lastUpdate;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    
Context mctx;
    private List<Item> itemList;
 

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public PlayFragment(Data data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_play, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       

      
    }






}
```

In the release version I have everything works on Pixel 2 and Xiaomi Redmi a4 android 6.0. How do I reproduce this error on my device or how do I know what is causing it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the overloaded method in `PlayFragment`. You should create fragments by using `newinstance()`, and `Fragment` must have the default constructor.